# Weird Behaviour of redirect in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I have built a login index page and i have made a controller with ModelAndView method to map to other jsp.
I'm trying to map the other jsp in the controller if the login credentials matches and if the credentials doesn't match then i'm redirecting to the index page with a message i.e. Sorry, username or password error. Here's the code:

```
return new ModelAndView("Redirect:/index.jsp","mess","Sorry, username or password error.");
```

This code redirects to the index page successfully but the message gets append to the url like this:

```
Localhost:8080/Project/index.jsp?"mess"+"="+"Sorry"
```

Like this.

My question is what is the reason for this issue. Why is the message getting appended in the url?
Any suggestion or opinion is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: uh? where is the code?

Comment: Sorry, the message didn't save. I just saved the edits again.

Comment: And how else should a parameter be passed through a redirect, which is a client side get. request....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RedirectView (instead of ModelAndView) and setExposeModelAttributes to false if you don't want to append to the url.

```
public class RedirectView extends AbstractUrlBasedView implements SmartView
```

`from spring documentation: 
View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current request relative URL. The URL may be a URI template in which case the URI template variables will be replaced with values available in the model. By default all primitive model attributes (or collections thereof) are exposed as HTTP query parameters (assuming they've not been used as URI template variables), but this behavior can be changed by overriding the isEligibleProperty(String, Object) method.`